# I have made an xml view to my app.but it isn't adjust on big screen phone or Tab .My xml code & xml view is given below

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#0fa1f5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="বাংলাদেশের সমুদ্র সৈকতের তালিকা"
            android:textColor="#f2efef"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/inani"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/inani_button" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cox"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cox_button" />
        </LinearLayout >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/potenga"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/potenga_button" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/kotka"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/kotka_button" />
        </LinearLayout >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/kuakata"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/kuakata_button" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/nijhum"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/nijhum_button" />
        </LinearLayout >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/technaf"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/technaf_button" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/saint"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/saint_button" />
        </LinearLayout >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/parki"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/parki_button" />
        </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout >
</ScrollView >
```

[this is my image that isnt fit on my tab screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDqNq.jpg)

Comment: Properly format your code. No one will answer otherwise. Maybe Jaqen H'gar will.

Comment: Is this XML layout correct?

Comment: yeah its correct & it works but not on the tab chatura Dilan

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used custom width and height for your image buttons, instead use only the layout_margin element to arrange your buttons and images on the screen.

dp stands for density independent pixels and hence the ratio is different for every device. That is why you are seeing such behavior, not just tab but i think it will show variations in every device.